# React Native Couldn’t find a navigation object. Is your component inside a screen in a navigator

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

> App.js

```
return (
    <NavigationContainer ref={navigationRef}>
        <Provider store={store}>

            <Router/>

        </Provider>
    </NavigationContainer>


);
```

> Router.js

```
<BabySitterStack.Navigator initialRouteName="BabySitterHome">
               {...}
</BabySitterStack.Navigator>
```

it gives an error when using use Navigation inside the router.js

I just want to make it like the example here, but it doesn't happen: https://rnfirebase.io/messaging/notifications#handling-interaction

thanks in advance for help

Comment: Please, share the full code of both components.